# Pie showing % spent with overlaid line showing % of timeline elapsed

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I give a regular budget update to a customer that prefers a pie chart.  The chart indicates how much of the total budget has been spent (full circle=total budget, slice 1 = expenses to date. Thus the bottom angle of the slice, in relation to the full circle, represents the percent spent). This part is easy.  I also want to show a LINE indicating where we are in the project timeline, on the same circle: full circle = 100% of timeline, line indicating percent of this timeline elapsed.

Currently, I accomplish this by pasting my pie chart into powerpoint and then hand drawing a line from the center of the circle to the perimeter of the circle, at an angle representing the percent of timeline elapsed.  I have to eyeball this which isn't ideal.

In the sample image, my hand drawn line is the green line. This chart shows that we are under spent (assuming a constant spend rate).  I prefer more complex and accurate ways of showing this data, but the customer wants this oversimplified format for execs.

Is there a way to accomplish this target or timeline LINE in a pie chart, or as a separate overlaid pie chart? I only want the time progress to be a line, not a pie slice.

*Sample Chart*:

[image: Hand Drawn Line - Pie Chart]

Comment: Have you looked at the Doughnut option in pie charts?